# Как передать значение из одной формы в другую?

Tags: php, form, input

Суть: со страницы товара из формы (стр 1 html) данные передаются на страницу корзины (стр 2 php) в форму, далее на страницу оплаты (стр 3 php). Сайт на html, без скриптов.

страница1

С неё передаются данные в форму на странице 2

Страница 2

```
<form action="action.php" id="form2" method="post">                                 
<input class="input1" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["222"]; ?>" name="product1" readonly>
<input class="input1" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["333"]; ?>" name="product2" readonly>
<input type="submit" value=" button ">
</form>
```

Страница 3
Как получить данные из формы на странице 2 на страницу 3

так не работает

```
Product2 name: <?php ($_POST["product1"]); ?>
Product3 name: <?php ($_POST["product2"]); ?>
```

Comment: Может надо `echo` написать?

Comment: Делал так, пустые поля выдает  Product2 name: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["product1"]); ?>
Product3 name: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["product2"]); ?>